# runtime error in simple Python code (NZEC)

Tags: python

I'm getting NZEC runtime error when running following code at SPOJ

link to the problem: 
http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY3/

my code:

```
a = int(input())
ans = []
for i in range(a):
    ans.append("NO")

for i in range(a):
    sum = 0
    print()
    x = int(input())
    f = []
    for l in range(x):
        f.append(0)

    for c in range(x):
        f[c] = int(input())
        sum = sum + f[c]
    if x != 0:
        if sum%x == 0:
            ans[i] = "YES"

for i in range(a):
    print(ans[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to at least run the code with the given example input:

```
$ python3 candy3.py < test.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "candy3.py", line 9, in <module>
    x = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Where `candy3.py` contains the code from your question and `test.txt` the following example input from the SPOJ assignment:

```
$ cat test.txt
2

5
5
2
7
3
8

6
7
11
2
7
3
4
```

If it doesn't run on your computer with the example input it most probably won't run on the SPOJ site with their real input.

Spoiler:

> You are not ignoring the blank line before every test case but try to convert this blank line into a number.

Comment: of course I tried it on my machine before submitting and it worked for all inputs and I tried your suggestion (by changing x = int(input("\n")) and removing print()  ) but it is giving the same error on SPOJ

Comment: @vik183 The code in your question and the example input from SPOJ lead to the exception. So it doesn't work. Every input according to the description at SPOJ will lead to that exception with your code. Your changes change the _output_ of your program, but the problem is you are not processing the _input_ to your program correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876845/my-every-python-code-gives-nzec-in-spoj)

> Basically you get nzec error or runtime error when your trying to access the array greater then its size or for some testcases your program may be running infinitely...
>
> At the last , their might be some logical error in your code , try extreme test case in your code .
>
> Since in spoj , the site is not maintained properly, for some question i tried i got tle in python and java but got AC in C and C++. This happen bcz the setter of the problem has not set the correct timing. This type of things have happen a lot to me .

Answer (score 0):

When we submit codes online, they give the input as a text file. Hence the inputs are in a single line. That's why we are getting NZEC error here.

Here, you might get it done by using **raw_input().split()** rather than using **int(input())** in the first line