# I got NZEC on the CANDY3

Tags: java, biginteger

I have been trying to solve the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY3/.
I wrote the following code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CANDY3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    BigInteger no_inputs = BigInteger.valueOf(s.nextInt()); 
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(no_inputs) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO, length = BigInteger.valueOf(s.nextInt());
        for (BigInteger j = BigInteger.ZERO; j.compareTo(length) < 0; j = j.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            BigInteger val = BigInteger.valueOf(s.nextInt());
            sum = sum.add(val);
        }
        if(sum.mod(length).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
    }
    s.close();
}
}
```

It runs perfectly on my computer using the sample input they gave but gives NZEC on spoj judge.

I saw the question [runtime error in simple Python code (NZEC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807877/runtime-error-in-simple-python-code-nzec) and that did not quite solve my issue as it is in python.

I have received this error quite many times in other problems, sometimes due to variable limits being exceeded and other reasons and every time it runs on my computer correctly. Please help and let me know how should I prevent it from coming in future.

My best guess is that the line gap between test cases is somehow causing problems.

Comment: Why on earth are you using BigIntegers? This is a simple problem for which ints probably will do nicely. I mean, there will not be trillions of candies on the table, right?

Comment: Well many were talking about overflow in the comments and advised to use BigIntegers...so I did. The question did not mention variable's limits but probably the test cases have such huge numbers.

Comment: Kids on a school trip? Huge numbers? **Overflow?** Why don't you try using ints instead of BigIntegers? Should improve on speed and memory use.

Comment: The empty line between test cases was indeed the problem in the Python question. I assume it is yours too. Read lines instead of nextInt() and check if they are empty.

Comment: FWIW, if you keep sum the modulo the number of kids, (file is max 1MB, so there can be no more than 1 million kids), ints will do very nicely. And ints are considerably faster than BigInts.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/20461842/) is the edit in the code using ints and using nextLine() and keeping only modulo of individual candies. Still NZEC on spoj whereas works like butter on my computer...still need help.

Comment: FWIW, what is NZEC?

Comment: Non Zero Exit Code

Comment: ISTM that you should modulo the sum, not the single numbers of  candies. Otherwise, it should work, I guess.

Comment: What causes this NZEC? The test program checking the results?

Comment: I added all the (individual candies modulo no. of children) and then did the modulo operation again on their sum. The individual modulo were done to save space. And yes, the test case gives correct results.

Comment: Perhaps you should trim() the strings read in before you send to parseInt. But this is only a guess. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Although I would do: `sum = (sum  + Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim())) % numKids;` and `if (sum == 0)`, but that should not make any difference.